# DataStax Devcenter export CSV format with "|" instead of ","

Tags: cassandra, export-to-csv, datastax

I'm looking for a way to change the delimiter of CSV files exported by DataStax DevCenter from a "," to a "|". Reason being that there are several array lists in my Cassandra data export that have commas already so a "," delimiter makes it challenging to parse the data once I open the export as CSV file and then try to open it to parse with another application. I'm using DevCenter v1.6.0

Comment: If you used a CSV parser to parse it then you wouldn't have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY table_name ( column , ... )
TO  'file_name'  
WITH option = 'value'
```

You can use DELIMITER option.
**Example:**

```
COPY table_name ( column , ... )
TO  'file_name'  
WITH DELIMITER= '|'
```

For list of other options please refer below link.

[COPY Command in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html)

Comment: Thanks, I used this command using Cqlsh and it worked for me. Unfortunately never found a solution through Devcenter, but this answer met my needs.